# Convolving 2D matrices of which one has many more data points

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I want to use Python to convolve 2 2D matrices. However, one of the matrices is quite 'coarse' (I have only one data point per meter, see *Data* in the code below) and the other matrix has a much higher resolution (20 data points per meter, see *Gaussian* in the code below).

To explain the problem better, I have made the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

std_x = 2.0
std_y = 2.0
A = 1/(2*np.pi*std_x*std_y)
Gaussian = A * np.exp(-(xx**2/(2*std_x**2) + yy**2/(2*std_y**2)))

#There is one datapoint for each meter, so the grid is 5 x 5 m
Data = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],\
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],\
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],\
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],\
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])

result = scipy.signal.convolve2d(Data, Gaussian, mode='same') 
#This does not give the right result, because it interprets Data as 20 times 
#as small as Gaussian, even though they should have the same size (in meters)
```

So between 0 and 5 (meter), *Gaussian* has 100 points in each direction, but *Data* has only 5 points. I want to convolve these matrices but I do not want to lose accurateness in my *Gaussian* matrix.

So what I want SciPy to interpret is this: 
[image]

But instead, it interprets it as (note the different x- and y-axes): 
[image][image]

What I think could be a solution, is to just make a Data matrix of the same size as *Gaussian* and copy the numbers 20 times in each direction, like:

```
Data = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, .... 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, ...., 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, ...., 3, 3, ......], 
                 [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, .... 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, ...., 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, ...., 3, 3, ......], 
                 ....
                 ....
                 [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, .... 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, ...., 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, ...., 3, 3, ......]])
```

This matrix could be directly convolved with the *Gaussian* matrix and would give the right (and most accurate possible) result.

However, I don't know how to make this matrix in a smart way. Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resample your coarse data --- below we create and plot coarse data (spacing = 1)

```
In [103]: import numpy as np 
     ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
     ...: from scipy.interpolate import interpn                                           

In [104]: x = np.linspace(0, 10, 11) ; y = x ; yc = y[:,None] 
     ...: z = (x-5)**2 - (yc-3)**2 ; plt.figure() ; plt.imshow(z) ;
```

[image]

and here we resample the data using [`scipy.interpolate.interpn`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interpn.html) --- first we have to construct a grid with shape `201, 201, 2` so that we have an entry for each resampled point and two values (*x* and *y*) for each point

```
In [105]: x1 = np.linspace(0,10,201) ; y1 = x1 
     ...: grid = np.array([(x,y) for x in x1 for y in y1]).reshape(201,201,2)
```

and finally do the actual resampling (using linear interpolation) and show the resampled data

```
z1 = interpn((x,y), z0, grid) ; plt.figure() ; plt.imshow(z1)
```

[image]

---

*Addendum*

We can define a function to resample a matrix specifying the number of
subdivisions in the row and in the column direction

```
def resample(z, nr, nc): 
    from numpy import arange, array, meshgrid 
    from scipy.interpolate import interpn 

    r, c = z.shape 
    r0, c0 = arange(r), arange(c) 
    r1, c1 = arange((r-1)*nr+1)/nr, arange((c-1)*nc+1)/nc 
    r1c1 = array(meshgrid(r1,c1)).transpose((2,1,0)) 
    return interpn((r0,c0), z, r1c1)

from numpy import ones
print(ones((3,4)))
print(resample(ones((3,4)), 1, 2)) # augmenting the columns
print(resample(ones((3,4)), 2, 1)) # augmenting the rows
```

prints

```
[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]]
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

Comment: Hi gboffi, 

This is exactly what I am looking for! Very smart to use interpolation. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of the attributes on the function

```py
scipy.signal.convolve2d(Gaussian, Data, mode='same')
```

From `help(convolve2d)`

```
convolve2d(in1, in2, mode='full', boundary='fill', fillvalue=0)
    Convolve two 2-dimensional arrays.

    Convolve `in1` and `in2` with output size determined by `mode`, and
    boundary conditions determined by `boundary` and `fillvalue`.
```

And then,

```
      ``full``
           The output is the full discrete linear convolution
           of the inputs. (Default)
        ``valid``
           The output consists only of those elements that do not
           rely on the zero-padding. In 'valid' mode, either `in1` or `in2`
           must be at least as large as the other in every dimension.
        ``same``
           The output is the same size as `in1`, centered
           with respect to the 'full' output.
```

**Edit**
To have the same *precision*, you should increase the number of points to have the same number of points per meter. Otherwise, it does not make physical sense.

```py
Data = np.repeat(np.array([x,x]),50,axis=0)
```

Which data is

```
array([[0.        , 0.05050505, 0.1010101 , ..., 4.8989899 , 4.94949495,
        5.        ],
       [0.        , 0.05050505, 0.1010101 , ..., 4.8989899 , 4.94949495,
        5.        ],
       [0.        , 0.05050505, 0.1010101 , ..., 4.8989899 , 4.94949495,
        5.        ],
       ...,
       [0.        , 0.05050505, 0.1010101 , ..., 4.8989899 , 4.94949495,
        5.        ],
       [0.        , 0.05050505, 0.1010101 , ..., 4.8989899 , 4.94949495,
        5.        ],
       [0.        , 0.05050505, 0.1010101 , ..., 4.8989899 , 4.94949495,
        5.        ]])
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your answer! I think I did not explain the problem correctly. I added a few images to my question to make it more clear. Do you understand what I mean? I think this is not doable without changing the `Data` matrix...

Comment: Okey, the data should have the same units in both sides to make sense. I will update my answer.